# how to redirect my www.example.com/index.html file www.example.com/index

Tags: .htaccess

how to redirect my **www.example.com/index.html** file  **www.example.com/index** using **.htacces**

and if my url is like www.example.com/test1/index.htm
or 
ww.example.com/test/test2/index.htm

how to redirect the pages with out extensions

```
# Redirect everyone but for me
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^127\.0\.0\.1
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com [R=302,L]
```

above code i found in web but it's not working ... how to specified .htacces rules

Answer (score 0):

You can use these rules in root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```